# How do I Configure paths in Blazor WASM that are on the same host but outside of Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have some Apps that are MVC in part and Blazor in other parts. Generally once I'm in Blazor, I can't get out. It captures every page request, locally giving not found errors for pages that would be served by controllers.

I had thought that there should be a way to configure this, for example a global setting for paths that Navigation Manager sees as External (even on same host). Maybe configuring /admin/ as a real whole page fetch (leaving the Blazor SPA altogether).

Does anybody have any idea how such a thing could be configured or implemented?

Thanks.

Comment: NavigationManager.NavigateTo(uri) - where uri is the full path to the target page...

Comment: That works for programed actions, but I am specifically asking about setup options because I'd want Blazor to know that some paths are 'outside' even during a Url change in the browser.